# css background can't find file in server

Tags: css

I looking in my code for about hour and couldn't catch what I am doing wrong. I have png and svg files and I can't set them as background in css.

This url is working:

```
background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") white no-repeat 98.5% !important;
```

Not working PNG:

```
background: url("images/arrow.png") #EEEEEE no-repeat 98.5% !important;
```

SVG:

```
background: url("images/arrow.svg") #EEEEEE no-repeat 98.5% !important;
```

Path for css: src/folder/style.css
Path for png and svg: src/folder/images/arrow.png or arrow.svg

Comment: Not sure I understood everything correctly. But have you tried to open the absolute path in your browser and see if you can open the files you are referring to? So: http://your-website.com/images/arrow.png ?

Comment: any 404 in console? else path looks fine to me